# FourierCosSeries of DiracDelta[x] mismatch

Tags: functions, distributions, fourier-analysis

When I do*

```
FourierCosSeries[DiracDelta[x - 0.0001], x, 5]
```

I get as a result

```
{0.140401, 1/\[Pi] + 0.63662 Cos[x] + 0.63662 Cos[2 x] + 0.63662 Cos[3 x] + 0.63662 Cos[4 x] + 0.63662 Cos[5 x]}.
```

Where each coefficient is a factor two too big. ([The Delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html))

Using

```
FourierSeries[DiracDelta[x], x, 5]
```

on the other hand, gives the correct result

```
{0.140401, 1/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(-I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(-2 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(2 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(-3 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(3 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(-4 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(4 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(-5 I x)/(2 \[Pi]) + E^(5 I x)/(2 \[Pi])}
```

(it is easy to see by using 2cos(x)=exp(ix)+exp(-ix) that the two expressions differ by a factor two)
So I know the correct expansion, but I prefer to trace back the origin of the mistake, to avoid similar wrong results in the future.

*The -0.0001 in the argument of the delta-function prevents me from getting a bunch of HeavisideTheta[0]'s in the answer

I tried another random symmetric function and the problem doesn't seem to persist there.

Comment: Have you looked up `FourierParameters`? The default normalization in *Mathematica* might be different than the one you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so FourierCosSeries only integrates from 0 to pi and doubles the result. For a symmetric function this is the same as integrating from -pi to pi.

As a consequence, in calculating the FourierCosSeries of DiracDelta[x] only the 'right halve' of the deltafunction counts as in the integration boundaries(hence Heavisidetheta[0]). Shifting the whole delta-function corresponds to having two delta-functions on [-pi,pi]